# Velocity and acceleration scaling

Tags: rviz, acceleration, ros-kinetic, ros-control, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not sure if this is the correct place to this question, but anyway I'm going to ask it in this forum. I'm controlling an UR10e robot with MoveIt and ROS, and I realized that the controllers crash when using high values of velocity and acceleration parameters in RViz (or MoveIt through a C++ pick and place node). What I cannot understand is why you must reduce robot operation speed, because controlling the robot using ROS does not let you use it at its full speed. Let's imagine you want the robot working in an Industrial Process or any other application controlled by ROS nodes. It doesn't make sense that this robot cannot work at its full speed if you need it. So why you must use this scaling factor when you are working with real robots? is it because of response time of the robot or calculation time needed when planing the movement between two waypoints?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327982/velocity-and-acceleration-scaling/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:
Just an observation: there is currently no official support for e-series robots in `ur_modern_driver`. So if you're using that (with the `216` PR) it's likely that there can/will be problems.

The only driver that will officially support e-series robots is the new driver worked on by FZI & UR. That is currently in beta.

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2019-07-09**:
Thank you. I know that there's no official support for e-series, but I know that you must use very low values for velocity and acceleration scaling in MoveIt because other users have already confirmed to me. But I was wondering if that scalation must be done with each robot and if so, why this happends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But I was wondering if that scalation must be done with each robot

No, that is purely a problem with the driver and your particular choice of robot at this point.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2019-07-09**:
Thank you very much!